# JS: Get an element's visible area coordinates

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need a function that can calculate the visible area of ​​an element that is currently visible on the screen without the part hidden by `overflow: scroll`, `position: absolute` etc.

That is, the result of this function `getVisiblePart(el)` will be `Visible Rect is: {x: 10, y: 20, height: 50, width: 700}`

**Background of the question:**
The need for such a function is due to a feature of the W3C specification for working with webdriver: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-interactability

> An element’s in-view centre point is the centre point of the area of the first DOM client rectangle that is inside the viewport.

Frameworks like selenoid/selenide for e2e tests use the w3c principle to calculate the center of the visible element [to move the cursor to it](https://selenide.org/2019/12/12/advent-calendar-actions/), while allowing you to specify an offset. The main problem is to find out the actual size of the visible area of ​​the element at the moment, in order to calculate the correct offsets, for example, to calculate the upper left border.

The solution to this problem for selenoid/selenide would be:

```js
Selenide.actions().moveToElement(el, getVisiblePart(el).width / -2, getVisiblePart(el).height / -2)
```

I have read a lot of similar topics, for example:

- [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123999/2051938) (it only answers the question whether the element has been seen or not)
- [How to check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487073/2051938) (same)
- [Is it possible to programmatically determine whether W3C action commands are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51974620/2051938) (close but no working answer)

All answers either give a boolean whether the element is visible, or fail to take into account that the element may be partially hidden `overflow: scroll`

Real Example with scrolls (I need to find visible `blue` rect position with any scroll position):

```css
.a {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.b {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.c {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}
#target {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-1px,-1px); /*because of border*/
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="target" />
```

In answer to this question, I have already partially solved this problem, achieved the result I needed using [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), but I do not consider this solution to be good, at least because it is not synchronous with when the function is called and on the issue of cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround based on [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

I do not consider this solution to be good, at least because it is not synchronous with when calling the function and on the issue of cross-browser compatibility.

This example perfectly demonstrates the final version that I want to get.

```js
var options = {
    // root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'),
    // rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1
}
var callback = function(entries, observer) {
    const r = entries[0].intersectionRect;
    document.getElementById('target').setAttribute('style', `top: ${r.top}px;left: ${r.left}px;height: ${r.height}px;width: ${r.width}px;`);
    observer.unobserve(c);
};

const c = document.querySelector('.c');
setInterval(() => {
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
  observer.observe(c);
}, 200);
```

```css
.a {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.b {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.c {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}
#target {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-1px,-1px); /*because of border*/
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="target" />
```

Explanation: every 200ms we calculate the visible area of ​​the blue element and highlight it.

An example of how I use this for **Selenide**:

```
    val containerSelector = "div.testEl"
    val rect = executeAsyncJavaScript<String>(
        "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                "var el = document.querySelector('" + containerSelector + "');" +
                "new IntersectionObserver(" +
                "    (entries, observer) => {" +
                "        observer.unobserve(el);" +
                "        var r = entries[0].intersectionRect;" +
                "        callback([r.x, r.y, r.height, r.width].map(v => Math.ceil(v)).join(','));" +
                "    }," +
                "    { threshold: 1 }" +
                ").observe(el);"
    )!!.split(',').toTypedArray();

    LEFT_TOP_X = rect[3].toInt() / -2 + 1 // +1 for Float tolerance
    LEFT_TOP_Y = rect[2].toInt() / -2 + 1 // +1 for Float tolerance

    // Move cursor to TOP LEFT
    Selenide.actions().moveToElement(el, LEFT_TOP_X, LEFT_TOP_Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

v2 may help but the asynch still stinks

https://github.com/szager-chromium/IntersectionObserver/blob/v2/explainer.md

https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/v2/

https://chromestatus.com/feature/5878481493688320

https://szager-chromium.github.io/IntersectionObserver/demo/cashbomb/hidden/

Comment: v2 just return boolean like "full visible" or no, but doesnt return current visible rect. Async... I have tried some experements with official w3c IntersectionObserverPolyfill, it works sync but looks like kludge. `const rect = IntersectionObserver.prototype._computeTargetAndRootIntersection(el,  getBoundingClientRect(el))` Demo: https://codepen.io/mixal_bl4/pen/abVdZYB